# How can I stop DBeaver firing a metadata query before each my queries?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I saw a demo using something like this

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
  WHERE "auto_suspend" IS NULL;
```

This allows to use the resultset from SHOW ... as part of a normal SQL statement.
**VERY** useful!

However, when I tried this in DBeaver, my LAST_QUERY_ID() always returned the result of something like "SELECT CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA()".

Which I discovered is precisely because DBeaver does this before any request.

Is it possible to stop this?

PS:
Of course, I can get the initial code to work by looking for an older query, like

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-2))) -- added -2
  WHERE "auto_suspend" IS NULL;
```

But i would prefer not to have to do this...

Comment: Same issue as described here for [DataGrip](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9537). Looks hardcoded to me as I cannot change it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around I like is to simply write the `SHOW` to a table. It makes it easier to use the result multiple times.

Also, if you use a transaction you don't need the `-2` or `Alt-X` for Execute script. So

```
BEGIN
  SHOW WAREHOUSES;
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE SHOW_WH AS 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
END;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM SHOW_WH WHERE "auto_suspend" IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that Snowflake themselves have released an extension for Visual Studio code and that does not suffer from this detail...

It does not solve the DBeaver thing... but...

And it does pretty good colour coding, intellisense, etc